# Query handlers in CQRS architectural pattern

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm starting with CQRS and I think I'm not quite sure how (or if it's Ok to do it) to add a query that can have filtering and ordering on the result of the final query.
For example:

```
public partial class GetParticipantListQuery : IRequest<IList<ParticipantDto>>
{
    public Expression<Func<ParticipantDto, bool>> Filter { get; set; } = null;
    public Func<IQueryable<ParticipantDto>, IQueryable<ParticipantDto>> OrderBy { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Then in the handler apply the filtering and ordering to the corresponding result from the DB
Is this a good option? How can I achieve this kind of thing in my queries? 
My goal is to avoid creating one query for each filter I need, like "GetParticipantsByNameQuery", "GetParticipantsByTeamIdQuery" and so on an so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a filter class which contains the necessary properties to filter the result.

For example:

```
public class Filter
{
    //Property Name
    public string Key { get; set; }
    //Property Type eg. string, int, bool
    public string Type { get; set; }
    //Value to filter
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

var result = from u in _context.Set<T>() select u;
switch(filter.Type)
{
    case "string":
        result = result.Where(e => EF.Property<string>(e, filter.Key).Equals((string)filter.Value));
}
```

This is just an example for string type, you can add your own type in the switch block to filter other types.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I've implemented a solution similar to your comment

Answer (score 1):

The way I approach my query side is as follows:-

I have a namespace that represents my query objects in order not to conflict with my domain.

The domain may be something like this:

```
namespace Product
{
    public class Order
    {
        public Guid Id { get; }
        public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; }

        public Order(Guid id, DateTime registeredDate)
        {
            Id = id;
            RegisteredDate = registeredDate;
        }
    }
}
```

The *read model* will look something like this (note the nested `Specification` class):

```
namespace Product.DataAccess.Query
{
    public class Order
    {
        public class Specification
        {
            public Guid? Id { get; private set; }
            public DateTime? RegisteredDateStart { get; private set; }
            public DateTime? RegisteredDateEnd { get; private set; }

            public Specification WithId(Guid id)
            {
                Id = id;

                return this;
            }

            public Specification WithRegisteredDateStart(DateTime registeredDateStart)
            {
                RegisteredDateStart = registeredDateStart;

                return this;
            }

            public Specification WithRegisteredDateEnd(DateTime registeredDateEnd)
            {
                RegisteredDateEnd = registeredDateEnd;

                return this;
            }
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my query layer I pass the specification over and the query layer can then construct the query using the specification values:

```
namespace Product.DataAccess
{
    public interface IOrderQuery
    {
        IEnumerable<Query.Order> Search(Query.Order.Specification specification);
        int Count(Query.Order.Specification specification);
    }
}
```

In this way you have an explicit requirement passed to your query layer and you refactor your specification class and the query implementation when you need further querying options.